# How to programmatically subscribe google apps user to company calendars right after creating them with Directory API?

Tags: google-oauth

I am provisioning accounts on my domain with the Directory API.

Right after I create the user, I want to subscribe them to a bunch of calendars as part of their account  setup.

Previously, I did this with ClientLogin by authorizing as the newly-created-user (because I knew the password). But ClientLogin has be deprecated.

Is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

You can do this by using service accounts to authenticate and act on behalf of the user without the user's knowledge.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount